# How do you make ship repairs (put out fires) in Star Command?

Tags: star-command

When attacks to your ship cause a fire, I'm not clear on how to repair to them. I think I was told that someone with engineering (yellow) skill is needed, but it's not obvious what I need to do to make them put out the fire.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to repair your ship, you need to move your engineers (yellow shirts) to the area that is damaged. Assign crew to your engine room to make engineers. Then you can tap on the crew member and then tap again to move them adjacent to the damaged area.

Comment: Make sure you don't tap ON the burning square, because engies are dumb enough to stand in a fire while trying to do repairs.

Comment: Although you certainly have an engine room, it is not necessary that the engineers doing the repair be assigned to that room; the other engineering rooms, Dodge Generator and Sentry rooms are also good.  If they have a yellow shirt on, they can put out fires.